# Jquery UI element won't appear

Tags: jquery

EDIT: Why on earth did I get voted down? Is it a problem to ask a question??? The question was researched BEFORE I asked it here and the reason I asked it here is because I did not know the answer.

I'm trying to use a slider element but the example code from [this](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax) site doesn't work, there's no slider appearing. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range with fixed maximum</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1,
      max: 10,
      value: 2,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Minimum number of bedrooms:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, what doesn't work? It works here: http://jsbin.com/yideyiquxu/edit?html,output. I just copied your code buddy!!!

Comment: Are you sure you succeed to get the js and css files?

Comment: Michael, the CSS is not included. I just copied the source code. I've tried with Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @alkopop79 How are you running? Using a server or a local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work for me. Are you running this from your local filesystem?

In that case you need to replace relative schemes with absolute schemes, and copy style.css to the same dir where you put your html file like so:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```